# Значение строк файла .bat проекта Firebird

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bat, firebird, cmake, project

Добрый день, пытаюсь собрать проект жарптицы по VS2015 но что то при копировании пути не видит, интересует как формируется путь к корневой папке:
в батнике он строится во так:

```
SET SERVER_NAME=localhost
 cd ..\..
 for /f "delims=" %%a in (' cd') do (set FB_ROOT_PATH=%%~sa)
 cd %~dp0
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (' echo %FB_ROOT_PATH:\=/%') do (set FB_DB_PATH=%%a)
```

однако, что это значит ума не хватает. Объясните пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось просто, если посмотреть на вывод то все становится ясно:

```
firebird-master\builds\win32>cd ..\..
firebird-master>for /F "delims=" %a in (' cd') do (set FB_ROOT_PATH=%~sa )
firebird-master>(set FB_ROOT_PATH=FIREBI~1 )
```

в общем прыгает на две папки вверх и присваивает текущий каталог